# Solving ODE issues

Tags: differential-equations, physics

Hello I am trying to solve and ODE system (basically solving the Schrodinger equation for a 2 level system). This is my code:

```
W = 5;
d = 1;
omega = 100000;
E0 = 1;
delta = 0.001;
eqns = {I*x'[t] == I*W + d*E0*Sin[omega*t]*y[t],
   I*y'[t] == -I*W + d*E0*Sin[omega*t]*x[t] + y[t]*delta, x[0] == 1, 
   y[0] == 0};
sol = DSolve[eqns, {x, y}, t]
Plot[{Abs[x[t]]^2 /. sol, Abs[y[t]]^2 /. sol}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

x and y will be complex functions of time, but what I need to plot is the square of the absolute value. However I am getting this error:

```
DSolve::dsvar: 0.0002042857142857143` cannot be used as a variable.

ReplaceAll::reps: {DSolve[{I (x^\[Prime])[0.000204286]==5 I+0.999966 y[0.000204286],I (y^\[Prime])[0.000204286]==-5 I+0.999966 x[0.000204286]+0.001 y[0.000204286],x[0]==1,y[0]==0},{x,y},0.000204286]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.
```

If I remove from the second ODE the last term (`y[t]*delta`) I don't get any error, but I get an empty plot. Can someone help me fix this issue (and get a plot with that term included)? Thank you!

Comment: `DSolve` doesn't solve the equation. Use `sol = NDSolve[eqns, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}][[1]]`

Comment: DId DSolve complete on your computer? How long did it take? Mine seems to hang for 5 minutes now.

Comment: Also, start by clearing your variables or clear everything with `Clear["Global\`*"]`

Comment: I tried it on Maple. Maple says there is no solution. So I have no idea how you got a solution on your computer.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks a lot! That worked!

Comment: @Nasser There is a solution. Actually if you set that term I mentioned to zero, the solution is analytical. But there is a solution with that extra term, too. And the run time is few seconds in Mathematica.

Comment: Well, I am using V 13.1 and on my computer it did not finish. I waited 10 minutes. Strange.

Comment: The mentioned warning is caused by polluted `t`. `Clear[t]` should resolve the problem. Then, is analytic solution necessary for you? If you just want a solution no matter it's numeric or analytic, use `NDSolve` as suggested by @Bob is the way to go.